# Return the first number found greater than the provided input number (13 digits)

Tags: performance, parsing, datetime, bash, logging

This script converts the numbers to be at least 13 characters long (for UNIX_MS strings). For use with timestamps, I'm having issues with it being very slow. I wanted an alternative to grepping for one specific `UNIX_MS` timestamp and not finding it and then having to grep multiple more times.

For the output I wanted the line number in the file (for slicing) as well as the original line (to confirm/inspect).

I'm very specifically looking for optimizations as I'd like this to be as-close-to-as-fast as grepping a single timestamp.

Usage: `./script.sh file UNIX_MS`

```
#! /bin/bash
# return the first number found that's greater than the provided input number
res=
linenum=
count=0
returnline=             # hold onto the line for return
tocheck=$2
tocheck=$(($tocheck*(10**(( ${#tocheck} - 13) * -1))))
inseconds=$(($tocheck/1000))
date=$(date -r $inseconds)
echo "Looking for first timestamp -ge to $date.."
while read line;
  do
    count=$(($count + 1))
    timearray=$(grep -o -E "^(.*?)([0-9]{10,13})?" <<< $line)
    if [ -z "$timearray" ]; then
    echo "PROBLEM"
        echo "grep -o -E '^(.*?)([0-9]{10,13})?' <<< $line"
        exit 1
    fi
    timestamp=$(sed -Ee "s/[0-9]+\://" <<< $timearray)
# normalize timestamp to be 13 digits
    if [ "${#timestamp}" -lt "13" ]; then
        mult=$((10**(( ${#timestamp} - 13) * -1)))
        timestamp=$(($timestamp * $mult))
    fi
    echo "$timestamp >= $tocheck?"
    linenum=$([ "$timestamp" -ge "$tocheck" ] && echo $count)
    if [ -z "$linenum" ]; then
        :;
    else
        returnline=$line 
    break;
    fi
done < $1
echo "$linenum:$returnline"
echo ""
```

Comment: Can you show sample input so we can benchmark?

Comment: Even if you don't show us the whole file for benchmarking, at least show a couple of representative sample lines of the log file.

Comment: Could you explain what the timestamp format is, such that you would want to zero-pad the numbers on the _right_ side?

Comment: It's unix milliseconds. See epochconverter.com.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you would want to zero-pad numbers on the right rather than on the left.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm having issues with it being very slow.

What makes your script code slow is that you're reading in the file yourself with the `while` loop, and apply `grep` to each single input line, instead of passing `grep` the file itself and let it just do it's job.

No matter what you want to search for with `grep`, you should always first pass your input to it with a single call, and inspect the results afterwards.

> For the output I wanted the line number in the file (for slicing) as well as the original line (to confirm/inspect).

`grep` already has this feature intrinsically (at least as it says from [this documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html)):

> > **`-n, --line-number`**
> >            Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file.

you simply can do what you want using this option.

Thus you can get rid of your `while` loop and `count` variable to determine the line number yourself.

Comment: How would you accomplish the numerical timestamp comparison, though?

Comment: @200_success From further inspection of the already produced results of a single run of grep? May be I misunderstood the question.

Comment: For speed I was attempting to output the first result without having to potentially read-in the entire file.

Comment: @octanepenguin `grep` will usually go through entire files very fast, you can expect that will be faster than using it multiple times and reading line by line yourself in the script. I hope I made my idea clear enough.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In my case though the files can be upwards of 20+ GB and a result can be in the middle. I get that I'm reading it line by line but how is that any different than grep? Surely it has to seek the file as well?

Comment: @octanepenguin `grep` is almost certainly implemented in c-language which will be most probably faster than an interpreted script to read a single line.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` has built-in regular expression support:

```
    if [[ $line =~ ^(.*?)([0-9]{10,13})? ]]; then
        timestamp=$BASH_REMATCH[2]
    else
        echo "PROBLEM!"
    fi
```

which completely removes need for `grep` and `sed`.